Drawer or a Fragment to show context screen of a page of information
I understand the Fragment is a newer replacement of Activity or within an activity?
To make a detail screen that pops up as a secondary "dialog" or drawer with more info - similar to Osmand... or EA:


In what cases would one use Drawer
or Fragment... or implement both working together for a drawer like this?
Note that this would show on one main screen with relevant details.
